# Docusign API text tab center alignment

Tags: docusignapi

I'm sending values into a Docusign template with the REST API. Is there a way to center the values in the text box?

```
{"tabLabel": "\\*Some label", "value": "Center me"}
```

I accidentally stumbled onto a centering technique when I send more white space on the left of the string value, like this:

```
"  1,200.00"
```

using python's `{:10,.f2}` formatting

[image]

Comment: What you really want is decimal alignment, right? Also, you could use a fixed width font now to help get things better aligned.

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no property/option available to specify the text alignment in the text tab.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Is it on a roadmap?

Comment: @FooL  What you really want is decimal alignment, right?

Comment: I want decimal alignment. Also, I want centering in a text box for other data that's not in a table like my image